# Entity Framework code first adding DbSet property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, generic-programming

I just started working with Entity Framework 6.1.2. I am using code first migration. I have around 78 entities in database. My question is that is there any way we can make the DbSet property generic in DatabaseContext class so I don't have to define all 78 properties?
For example

```
    public class DatabseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Models> Models { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Rights> Rights { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't want to make all these properties. Instead I want one generic property or function to return the DbSet of respective type.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `DbContext` already contains a generic method `Set<T>()`, you can call that directly as it is public. Example: `var allUsers = contextInstance.Set<User>().ToList();` Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  But you really shouldn't.

You can register entity types in `OnModelCreating` without having a `DbSet<T>`.  EG:

```
class Db : DbContext
{
    public Db(string constr) : base(constr) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                  .GetTypes()
                                  .Where(t => t.Namespace == "MyApp.Entities");

        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(entityType);
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

But you'll always have to access the Entities through [DbContext.Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).